# Output in Julia Escher.jl in web very plain

Tags: r, julia

So, I have this code `r.jl` and I am fully newbie to this and this is only a school projects, yes it suppose to be easy using shiny in r, but my professor doesn't want something simple:

```
using RCall
using ImageView, Images 

R"library(NLP)"
R"library(RColorBrewer)"
R"library(tm)"
R"library(SnowballC)"
R"library(e1071)"
R"library(gplots)"
R"library(ROCR)"
R"library(gmodels)"
R"library(caret)"
R"library(xtable)"
R"sms_raw <- read.csv('/home/r/sms_spam.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)"
R"str(sms_raw)"
R"summary(sms_raw)"
R"sms_raw$type <- factor(sms_raw$type)"

R"sms_results <- read.csv('/home/r/sms_results.csv')"
R"confusionMatrix(sms_results$predict_type, sms_results$actual_type, positive = 'spam')"
R"pred <- prediction(predictions = sms_results$prob_spam, labels = sms_results$actual_type)"
R"perf <- performance(pred, measure = 'tpr', x.measure = 'fpr')"

    R"plot(perf, main = 'ROC curve for SMS spam filter', col = 'blue', lwd = 2)"



using Compose
using Colors

# define the `sierpinski` triangle function
function sierpinski(n)
    if n == 0
        compose(context(), polygon([(1,1), (0,1), (1/2, 0)]))
    else
        t = sierpinski(n - 1)
        compose(context(),
                (context(1/4,   0, 1/2, 1/2), t),
                (context(  0, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2), t),
                (context(1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2), t))
    end
end

main(window) = compose(sierpinski(6))

function main(window)
    # load assets
    push!(window.assets, "layout2")
    push!(window.assets, "tex")

    # create the tabs
    tabbar = tabs([
         hbox("Sierpinski"),
         hbox("R"),
         hbox("R"),
     hbox("R"),
     hbox("R"),
     hbox("R"),
     hbox("R"), 

    ])

    # create the pages
    tabcontent = pages([
        sierpinski(5),
        R"str(sms_raw)",
    R"confusionMatrix(sms_results$predict_type, sms_results$actual_type, positive = 'spam')",
    R"png('rplot.png')",
    image("/root/.julia/v0.4/Escher/examples/myplot.png"),
    tex("Help  Me"),
    title(3, "T "),


    ])

    # connect the tabs to pages
    # returns a pair of "connected" tab set and pages
    t, p = wire(tabbar, tabcontent, :tab_channel, :selected)

    # stack them on top of each other
    vbox(t, p)
end
```

So I use julia with Escher.jl and embed R and then the output in web like this

[Way too plain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD0e7.png)

The output is weird. Not like in Rstudio like this:

[Output that easier and right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RszHh.png)

Help Me, I don't understand what I am doing, I just want static web output with R (and I am forbidden to use Rook, or other things like shiny) but to be embed in others things. My Professor is so complicated

So I'm using Escher.jl and RCall.jl

Comment: What about trying to `println` the `R"confusionMatrix(sms_results$predict_type, sms_results$actual_type, positive = 'spam')"`?

Comment: so `printlnR"confusionMatrix(sms_results$predict_type, sms_results$actual_type, positive = 'spam')" `

Comment: still cant @ShaoWeiTeo . other  ? but thank you, and the output now is nothing....

Comment: Sorry that was a bad try... what about using the `rcopy` function in `RCall.jl`? The function is exported, so you can just use `rcopy(R"confusionMatrix(sms_results$predict_type, sms_results$actual_type, positive = 'spam')")`...

Comment: its weirder.... sorry this is too hard... im sorry....

Comment: Actually Julia is an easier language to learn and use, so it is a pity to see you stop halfway. I believe your Prof does not intend to make things unnecessarily hard for you, but meant for you to study Julia deeply to get the same statistic competency you currently have in R. Trying to run R model with Julia's view is kinda weird choice in my opinion. Nevertheless, I understand that trying Julia is not voluntary for you, and I look forward to the day when you turn back and give it a try one more time. All the best at school! =)

Comment: `image("/root/.julia/v0.4/Escher/examples/myplot.png")` eventually R could export as image, so how to view image in julia escher.jl ? my code doesnst show anything...

Comment: Hmm... Let me give you a direction... The `RCall.jl` library does not convert a string in R to a string in Julia directly, nor does it convert a R image into an image in Julia, it convert to an object containing R data. So another conversion is required. The good thing about Julia is that, everything is readable in the code. You may visit the `\src` folder in the `RCall.jl` directory, and read the source code from there. It will give you the necessary correction you need to do to continue ahead.

Comment: okay, how to import image ? i just want to show image, i got other way, i think...

Comment: Hmm? You are using the image in your local folder. You will need to read it in first using the `imread` function from the `Images.jl` package. Instruction can be found here: http://escher-jl.org/content-api.html

Comment: okay, another packages

Comment: Yupz, same as R =)